# ASP.NET Core update seeded identity data in Program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

My `Program.cs` is seeding my authentication database with basic data (roles, claims, etc...):

```
var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

if (!roleManager.Roles.Any())
{
    roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Xyz)).Wait();
    // ....
    roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim("Permission", claim)).Wait();
}
```

Now my authentication database has been created and later on I want to remove some claims from some roles. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you please how did you seeded your identity values and when you are saying want to remove some claims by that what do you want to remove? Please share few more details in order to reprouce your scenario. But in general you can use [`RemoveClaimAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.removeclaimasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to remove claims